# php: call_user_func not working as expected

Tags: php, function

i wrote some lines of code for dynamically executing a function like this:

```
$fn= "generatesomeHTML";
$html = call_user_func($fn);
```

the strange thing is - it works locally but not on my live server where the call_user_func returns null (for variable $html). any ideas what could be wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what the function `generatesomeHTML()` looks like? Also which versions of PHP are you running on your Server and your dev environment?

Comment: what does `var_dump( is_callable( $fn ));`  return ?

Comment: @tereško: returns both bool(true)

Comment: function generatesomeHTML(){ return "bla bla";}

Answer (score 1):

sorry was my fault .. the live version's function actually returned a zero value :(